# How to get Text from Parent div only using Jsoup in Android

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I am working with `Android Application` using `Jsoup` for `extracting` text from `website`, in the below `Html` I want to get text of the `parent div` only. What I want is to display `Date & Time` which is in the `parent div` of `class "fr"`.

```
<div class="fr">
        <div id="newssource">
            <a href="http://nhl.com" class="newssourcelink" target="_blank">
                Philadelphia Flyers
            </a>
        </div>
        April 15, 2014, 11:13 a.m.
    </div>
```

What I have tried.

```
for(Element detailsDate:document.getElementsByClass("fr")){
    newsDate.add(detailsDate.clone().children().remove().last().text().trim());
}
```

It only get text from `child div` i.e. `"Philadelphia Flyers"` which is in the `"a" tag`, but I want to display the `Date & Time` only.

Comment: Any one know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by myself. Just Posted here for some one else with same issue.

```
for(Element detailsDate:document.getElementsByClass("fr")){
    newsDate.add(detailsDate.getElementById("newssource").nextElementSibling());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below jQuery code to get only Date and Time form "fr" div

```
<script>
 jQuery('.fr').each(function(){
  var textValue = jQuery(this).clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
  alert(textValue);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I need java code not JavaScript I m working with android jsoup as I mentioned in my question

Comment: .end() is not supported in Java using Jsoup, so i use .last() as an alternative, my code is same as you mention in you Answer, but still its only get child text not parent's