# How to capture exact h3 text in this case

Tags: jquery

I have got h3 tag  text as **Haii** OR **rerrrwe**

http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/14/

When i try to capture the h3 text , its adding some sattic text also as "click to collapse contents "

Haii  click to collapse contents

Could you please let e know how to capture the exact text ??

This is my program

```
var response = {
    "Restaurants": [{
        "RestrntArea": "Haii",
        "cust_loc_id": "374"
    }, {
        "RestrntArea": "rerrrwe",
        "cust_loc_id": "373"
    }]
}
showLabels();

function showLabels() {
    //$("#result").html("");
    var favoriteresultag = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < response.Restaurants.length; i++) {
        var name = response.Restaurants[i].RestrntArea;
        if (name) {
            favoriteresultag += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" class="my-collaspible"><h3>' + name + ' <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon "></a></h3></div>';
        }
    }
    $("#result").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my-collaspible').bind('expand', function() {
        //alert('Expanded');
        var name = $(this).find('h3').text();

        alert(name);
        console.log(name);


    });
    $('.my-collaspible').bind('collapse', function() {
        //alert('Collapsed');
    });
});
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this??

Comment: Please run the jsfiddle and click on either of the Collasable elements

Comment: Thanks , you mean this way  var name = $(this).find('h3 .ui-btn-text').text();

Comment: Please share a normal piece of code with us, not almost 6000 lines.

Comment: No problem , i have managed with   elemclciked = elemclciked.replace('  click to collapse contents','');

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is another solution**

```
   var response = {
        "Restaurants": [{
            "RestrntArea": "Haii",
            "cust_loc_id": "374"
        }, {
            "RestrntArea": "rerrrwe",
            "cust_loc_id": "373"
        }]
    }
showLabels();

function showLabels() {
    //$("#result").html("");
    var favoriteresultag = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < response.Restaurants.length; i++) {
        var name = response.Restaurants[i].RestrntArea;
        if (name) {
            favoriteresultag += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" class="my-collaspible"><h3><span>' + name + '</span> <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon "></a></h3></div>';
        }
    }
    $("#result").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my-collaspible').bind('expand', function() {
        //alert('Expanded');
        var txt = $(this).find('h3 .ui-btn-text span').html();

        alert(txt);
        console.log(name);


    });
    $('.my-collaspible').bind('collapse', function() {
        //alert('Collapsed');
    });
});
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/15/

Comment: my solution doesnt need trimming and cloning

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your element has children that have text inside of them as well. Target the specific element, clone it, grab the children, remove them, end the chain to revert back to original selector, grab the text.

```
var name = $(this).find('h3 .ui-btn-text').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

[Here's your working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxgkhL1q/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have more child elements inside your `h3` that also have text this is the solution you need:

```
var name = $(this).find('h3 .ui-btn-text').clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()      //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23364910/1524085

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of the generated html of the h3 tag; judge for yourself what the jQuery should be:

```
<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c" data-mini="false">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner">
            <span class="ui-btn-text">
                rerrrwe <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon  ui-link"></a>
                <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span>
            </span>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</h3>
```

Why are you using jQM with jQuery UI anyway? I though the two, especially the versions you've selected, don't play well together!

```js
var name = $('h3').find( 'span span' ).contents()[0].nodeValue;
alert( name.trim() )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
        <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c" data-mini="false">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">
                    rerrrwe <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon  ui-link"></a>
                    <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span>
                </span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
<script>
var response = {
    "Restaurants": [{
        "RestrntArea": "Haii",
        "cust_loc_id": "374"
    }, {
        "RestrntArea": "rerrrwe",
        "cust_loc_id": "373"
    }]
}
showLabels();

function showLabels() {
    //$("#result").html("");
    var favoriteresultag = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < response.Restaurants.length; i++) {
        var name = response.Restaurants[i].RestrntArea;
        if (name) {
            favoriteresultag += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" class="my-collaspible"><h3>' + name + ' <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon "></a></h3></div>';
        }
    }
    $("#result").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my-collaspible').bind('expand', function() {
        //alert('Expanded');
        var name = $(this).find('h3 .ui-btn-text').clone().children().remove().end().text();

        alert(name);
        console.log(name);


    });
    $('.my-collaspible').bind('collapse', function() {
        //alert('Collapsed');
    });
});
</script>
```