# How to remove only text between two different Tags using JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

```xml
<div class="orcl6w2">
  <div class="orcl6w3">
    <table >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <center>
                      <strong>As Published In </strong>                                      
                    </center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <h2>DEVELOPER: PL/SQL Practices</h2>
            <hr />
            <strong>Steven Feuerstein </strong>This has to be deleted                                                        
            <em>Oracle PL/SQL Programming</em>This has to be deleted too.                                                             
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to delete the text as well as tag after `hr` tag. i.e.,

```xml
<hr />
<strong>Steven Feuerstein </strong>This has to be deleted                                                        
<em>Oracle PL/SQL Programming</em>This has to be deleted too.
```

I tried to delete by using the below code. But with the below code only i'm able to delete the tag that is after `hr` tag. But i'm unable to delete the text i.e., `This has to be deleted` and `This has to be deleted too.`.

```
if (elements.select("hr").size() > 0) {
    final Element hrfound = elements.select("hr").last();
    final int hrIdx = hrfound.siblingIndex();

    for (Element e : hrfound.siblingElements()) {
        if (e.siblingIndex() > hrIdx) {
            e.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help....

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364404/how-to-get-text-from-parent-div-only-using-jsoup-in-android) related question might help you.

Comment: May it be caused by the fact that the second's element index decreases by one when its previous sibling is removed?

Comment: Hey lzruo... Thanks for your effort.. I really tried by that link you provided... But i was unable to fix the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method (`hrfound.siblingElements()`) you are using only gets `Element` objects, but the text you are trying to delete as well is of type `Node`. I also wouldn't try to remove them by using the indexes. Instead, after finding the `hr` element, you can use the `nextSibling()` method to get the siblings after that; it will select type `Node` so it will get both the elements as well as the text nodes.

The below code should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
while(hrfound.nextSibling() != null) {
    hrfound.nextSibling().remove();
}
```

Comment: It worked for me Justin.... Thanks for the help... I got completely stuck in this issue. Now it got resolved... Thanks again..